# How can I increment a value in scheme with closure?

Tags: scheme

How can I increment a value in scheme with closure? I'm on lecture 3A in the sicp course.

```
(define (sum VAL)

    // how do I increment VAL everytime i call it?

    (lambda(x)  
        (* x x VAL)))

(define a (sum 5))

(a 3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `set!` for storing the incremented value. Try this:

```
(define (sum VAL)
  (lambda (x)
    (set! VAL (add1 VAL))
    (* x x VAL)))
```

Because `VAL` was enclosed at the time the `sum` procedure was called, each time you call `a` it'll "remember" the previous value in `VAL` and it'll get incremented by one unit. For example:

```
(define a (sum 5)) ; VAL = 5

(a 3)  ; VAL = 6
=> 54  ; (* 3 3 6)

(a 3)  ; VAL = 7
=> 63  ; (* 3 3 7)
```

Answering the comment: sure, you can use `let`, but it's not really necessary, it has the same effect as before. The difference is that in the previous code we modified an enclosed function parameter and now we're modifying an enclosed `let`-defined variable, but the result is identical. However, this would be useful if you needed to perform some operation on `n` before initializing `VAL`:

```
(define (sum n)
  (let ((VAL n))
    (lambda (x)
      (set! VAL (add1 VAL))
      (* x x VAL))))
```

Comment: @runners3431 well, yes ... but it's not necessary. See my updated answer.